# upgrade android SDK version in react native

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I am trying to upgrade android SDK version 30 to 31 . My build is happening fine while the time of installation I am facing the below issue .

**The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED**

My other SDK versions are like

```
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 31  // Updated
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
```

My react-native version is 0.59.9 . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding below code into AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:exported="true"
```

Like this

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:exported="true">
.....
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the manifest entries representing the entry points of your application contain an explicit value for the `android:exported` attribute. It requires from API level 31+.

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:exported="true">
   .....
</activity>
```

For more: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/android-exported